# Creating new column by mapping to dictionary (with string contain match)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I am trying to create in `df1` the column `Factor` based on the dictionary `df2`. However the `Code` columns for mapping are not exactly the same and the dictionary only contain the `Code` strings partially.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'],
    'Ratings':[9.0, 8.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2, 3, 6, 5],
    'Code':['R:EST 5R', 'R:EKG EK', 'R:EKG EK', 'R:EST 5R', 'R:EKGP', 'R:EST 5R', 'R:OID_P', 'R:OID_P']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code':['R:EST', 'R:EKG', 'R:OID'],
    'Factor':[1, 1.3, 0.9]})
```

So far, I wasn't able to map the data frames correctly, because the columns are not exactly the same. The column `Code` does not necessary start with "R:".

```
df1['Factor'] = df1['Code'].map(df2.set_index('Code')['Factor'])
```

This is how the preferred output would look like:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'],
    'Ratings':[9.0, 8.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2, 3, 6, 5],
    'Code':['R:EST 5R', 'R:EKG EK', 'R:EKG EK', 'R:EST 5R', 'R:EKGP', 'R:EST 5R', 'R:OID_P', 'R:OID_P'],
    'Factor':[1, 1.3, 1.3, 1, 1.3, 1, 0.9, 0.9]})
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> df1['Code'].str[:5].map(df2.set_index('Code')['Factor'])
0    1.0
1    1.3
2    1.3
3    1.0
4    1.3
5    1.0
6    0.9
7    0.9
Name: Code, dtype: float64

>>> (df2.Code
         .apply(lambda x:df1.Code.str.contains(x))
         .T
         .idxmax(axis=1)
         .apply(lambda x:df2.Factor.iloc[x])
)

0    1.0
1    1.3
2    1.3
3    1.0
4    1.3
5    1.0
6    0.9
7    0.9
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The "Code" is not necessarily always in the beginning. Is there also a way with a string contain function?

Comment: df2.Code.apply(lambda x:df1.Code.str.contains(x)).T.idxmax(axis=1).apply(lambda x:df2.Factor.iloc[x])